# How can I model a process which follows a pdf that changes w.r.t time?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, stochastic-processes

I'm interested in modeling the probability of a gym having had k number of arrivals at time = t. Clearly this should be modeled by some type of time cont. stochastic process but a poisson process will not work because it assumes a constant mean whereas in reality, the mean clearly changes w.r.t time. (lots more arrivals in the morning and late afternoon than the rest of the day)

Is this too complicated to work out via probability theory? Is it easier to collect arrival data and create an empirical cdf? That seems kind of crazy to actually go do.

Comment: A Non-homogeneous Poisson process (section 2.4 of http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-262-discrete-stochastic-processes-spring-2011/course-notes/MIT6_262S11_chap02.pdf , and you can look at theorem 2.4.1 for your use) allows the arrival rate to vary as a function of time.  But don't you have such things as batch arrivals due to groups of people arriving together - although maybe that level of granularity is not important for your application. As to whether you'll be better off just using an empirical CDF?

Comment: See the remarks on [simple temporal point processes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TemporalPointProcess.html).